# timestamp в PHP

Tags: php

Прочитал на досуге, что преобразовать `timestamp` в нормальную дату можно при помощи той же `date();` Однако, работает некорректно. Кто что может посоветовать ?

Например, вводя `$date = date("d.m.Y H:m",time());`
я получаю `12.12.2019 13:12`. Дата правильная, а вот время косячное..Должно быть 13:40
Вот timestamp = 1576158050

Как решить ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что формат 'm' который вы указываете для минут не верен нужно использовать 'i'

[Здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php) подробнее. В итоге будет `date("d.m.Y H:i",time());`

Comment: Спасибо, понял!

Comment: @steam.apk2 если вам помог мой ответ, то отметьте его как решение